# Is it possible to compress a URL?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

Is it possible to compress a random URL

```
https://a.scdn.gr/images/sku_main_images/014650/14650949/20180416114151_amd_ryzen_5_2600.jpeg
```

into a much smaller text like this one?

```
ta7f^*(GD&FY6FTGsdfsfYHU(*
```

If you had to deal with millions of URLs that share some part how would you compress them?

```
https://a.scdn.gr/images/sku_main_images/014650/14650949/20180416114151_amd_ryzen_5_2600.jpeg
https://a.scdn.gr/images/sku_main_images/014650/14650949/20180416114151_amd_ryzen_5_2700.jpeg
https://a.scdn.gr/images/sku_main_images/014650/14650949/20180416114151_amd_ryzen_5_2700x.jpeg
...
```

My way would be to:

1. Make a base-256 counter.

Base-10 can count up to 9999 with 4 digits.

1-byte can represent 256 symbols

Base-256 can count up to 4,294,967,296 with 4 digits.

2. Break each URL into parts and index it using base-256.

For example, "**http://**" is at number **0**, "**a.scdn.gr**" is at number **56762835** which is represented as **%&r** in base-256.

3. Save each URL as a sequence of indexes.

For example,

```
https://a.scdn.gr/images/sku_main_images/014650/14650949/20180416114151_amd_ryzen_5_2700.jpeg
```

is converted to 7 parts:

```
0/&^T/&^Y/&^e/*JE/(E*U/*EHG
```

I will need to do 7 separate fetches of the parts but I don't care since I will do critical processing on a few URLs at a time, problem is storing them.

I will save a million times the text "**&^T/**" and once the text "**index:&^T, content:a.scdn.gr/**" instead of saving a million times the text "**a.scdn.gr/**"

~50% compression.

**Example**

1-byte
8-bits
256 symbols

base-10: 1943 = 0x10^4 + 1x10^3 + 9x10^2 + 4x10^1 + 3x10^0 = "1", "9", "4", "3"

base-256: 1943 = 0x256^3 + 0x256^3 + 0x256^2 + 7x256^1 + 151x256^0 = "$", "*" ($=7, *=151)

Comment: you said that `56762835 is represented as %&(r`, how will you present `0` and `4,294,967,296` in printable ascii symbols?

Comment: in base-10 the symbol for 1 and the symbol for 0 make 10, "10". in base-256 the symbol for 256 (which might be &) and then symbol for 1 (which I declare 1) make 257, "&1". "257" takes 3 digits while "&1" takes 2 digits but they both represent "257".

Comment: if the part is less than 4 digits its a waste. for example "r/" from reddit URLs might be saved a million times as "(&*/" which is 3 digits.

Comment: please take a look at the example i've added to the main post.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder